# Ignore Some % Parameters in Format String

Tags: string, printf, string-formatting

Since format strings show up so often, I sometimes run into the situation where I need to format a string, and then send that string into a second function for formatting again. For instance, I need to use a command line tool for converting images into video and the command line tool expects image%d as an input.

I have tried a few different ways of doing this such as putting a %s statement in the format string and passing a %d to fill in the %s, but it seems like sometimes they work and sometimes they do not. I have also tried \%\d, but that does not seem to work either.

```
char *dir = "workingdirectory";
char *moviename = "movie.mp4";

char buffer[1000];//The string to pass to system
sprintf("avconv %s/image%s.png %s",dir,"%d",moviename);//This statement is not quite correct for this tool, because I only included inputs and outputs.
//Desired string: "avconv workingdirectory/image%d.png movie.mp4"

system(buffer);
```

When I run this code for some reason a large integer shows up where the %d should be. What is a safe/reliable way to leave % statements in strings after they have been formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried escaping the % with %% in the first instance so its treated as a string and then replacing occurrences of %% with % in the second instance which will return it to being a format specifier?